# How do I hide/show a field in crystal reports based on the value of another field?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have 2 fields in the report, when 1 field is null or blank then the other field will be visible. Note that the field is blank/null because the query for the report didn't return any results, i'm not actually passing a " " value to the field.

`If {Table1.StringColumn} = " " then true else false`

This doesn't seem to work for some reason but I have another report where I did something similar to this and it works fine, the only difference is the other report is a number and I had something like `If {Table1.NumberCol} = 0 then true else false`

I'm putting this in the formula editor besides suppress.

Answer (score 0):

Giving space is not same as null.. both are diffenet so in your case formula should be.

```
If {Table1.StringColumn} = "" then true else false
```